# Injected Spring Bean is NULL in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am using Spring Boot(1.5.3) to develop a REST Web Service. In order to take some action on incoming request I have added an interceptor shown below.

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
RequestParser requestParser;


@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    //HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    requestParser.parse(request);
    return true;
}
}
```

`RequestInterceptor` has an autowired Spring Bean `RequestParser` responsible for parsing the request.

```
@Component
public class RequestParserDefault implements RequestParser {

@Override
public void parse(HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("Parsing incomeing request");
}

}
```

Interceptor registration

```
@Configuration  
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/usermanagement/v1/**");
}
}
```

And my Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);

}
}
```

Now when a request comes in, it lands in `preHandle` method of `RequestInterceptor` but `RequestParser` is NULL. If I remove the `@Component` annotation  from `RequestParser` I get an error during Spring context initialization `No bean found of type RequestParser`. That means `RequestParser` is registered as Spring bean in Spring context but why it is NULL at the time of injection? Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably needs a `@ComponentScan` of the package where `RequestParserDefault` is located.

Comment: @IndraBasak I believe it is able to find and register the bean since I am getting an error during context initialization if I remove the `@Component` annotation from it.

Comment: Did you register `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: @IndraBasak yes, and the request is reaching the interceptor.

Comment: Please post how you are adding the interceptor.

Comment: @IndraBasak I have added the code but I don't think that is the cause of it.

Comment: When you create a class using new which you did: new RequestInterceptor(), it is no longer a spring bean. It becames normal class. Thats why the field is not injected. You can inject your bean to WebMvcConfig, and use it

Comment: Since you are instantiating the bean `RequestInterceptor` by yourself, you have to create the `RequestParserDefault` too. e.g., `registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor(new RequestParserDefault())).addPathPatterns("/usermanagement/v1/**");`

Comment: @mlecz yeah, that was the gap, I was explicitly creating the instance of `RequestInterceptor` didn't realize that was not being registered as Spring bean. thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in this `new RequestInterceptor()`.
Rewrite your WebMvcConfig to inject it, e.g. like this:

```
@Configuration  
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  

  @Autowired
  private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .addPathPatterns("/usermanagement/v1/**");
  }
}
```